# Remove row from Datatable and from Access Database VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable, dataview

I am trying to delete a row from my Access database.

I have an Access table bound to dataview and then this dataview serves as datasource for my listbox. I am deleting a row from the listbox and is being removed, but it is not being removed from my Access database.

Any idea why it is not working?

```
Dim valueTofind As DataRow = EQDATADataSet.EQTYP_tbl.Rows.Find(lbxeq_sTtem)
EQDATADataSet.EQTYP_tbl.Rows.Remove(valueTofind)
EQDATADataSet.EQTYP_tbl.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Do you know what [AcceptChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges?view=netframework-4.8) does?

Comment: commits changes made to the datatable..

Comment: No, it doesn't.  From the link: `When AcceptChanges is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: all Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.`  Here is the next important part: `The AcceptChanges method is generally called on a DataTable after you attempt to update the DataSet using the DbDataAdapter.Update method.`

Comment: You cant bind an access table to a DataView. You can bind an Access table to a DataTable. A dataview is derived from DefaultView of DataTable

Comment: ok. I added access table as datasource ..then added one of the table to dataview. see the image https://ibb.co/xjXnt8r

Comment: i want to commit my changes made to datatable to access database ..how do i do that? cheanges are being made to the datatable / dataset but not to database